# TableCalendar Not Updating State Correctly

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, calendar

I have a list, so something like

```
var x = [DateTime(xxxx), DateTime(xxxx)];
```

And I want to show users the days they worked out, so I want the days in that list to appear green, lets say. However, when I navigate to a new month and sometimes just navigate at all, the green circle disappears. I know my function is used correctly, because the font size differs from the default text, but it doesn't show the circle. I included images of the issue and the code for the calendar is linked below. Thank you!

```
                           Container(
                              width: size.width * .9,
                              child: TableCalendar(
                                firstDay: DateTime.utc(1900, 10, 16),
                                lastDay: DateTime.utc(2200, 3, 14),
                                availableGestures:
                                    AvailableGestures.horizontalSwipe,
                                focusedDay: _focusedDay,
                                calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
                                selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                                  return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
                                },
                                key: _calendarKey,
                                daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
                                    weekdayStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).secondaryText),
                                    weekendStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).secondaryText)),
                                calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                                    selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).darkGreen,
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                    isTodayHighlighted: false,
                                    todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: AppColors(theme).primaryText,
                                    ),
                                    defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).primaryText,
                                        fontSize: 20),
                                    weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).primaryText,
                                        fontSize: 20),
                                    outsideTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).primaryText),
                                    outsideDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    )),
                                onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selectedDay = selectedDay;
                                    _focusedDay = focusedDay;
                                    sortExercises();
                                  });
                                },
                                
                                calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                                    defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
                                  bool workedOut = worked_out_days.any(
                                      (workedOutDay) =>
                                          isSameDay(workedOutDay, day));
                                  return workedOut
                                      ? Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: AppColors(theme).footerGrey,
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          ),
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              '${day.day}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: AppColors(theme)
                                                    .primaryText,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : null;
                                }),
                                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                                    leftChevronVisible: false,
                                    rightChevronVisible: false,
                                    formatButtonVisible: false,
                                    titleCentered: true,
                                    headerMargin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors(theme).primaryText,
                                        fontSize: 20)),
                                onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _focusedDay = focusedDay;
                                  });
                                },
                              ))
```

You can see in the image the 25, 26, 27, 28, and 29 for feb is selected (with a grey circle), but when I go to march, only 1 and 2 are selected, not 25, 26, 27, 28, and 29.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it with a stateful builder?
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

Comment: @NiladriRaychaudhuri It's not really the state issue, it's more the outside days not updating. So if I go to march 1st it doesn't go through my calendar builder